# Split Heroku Web Workers by URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Firstly: I realise in an ideal world I could achieve this using SOA. Humour me :)

#### Background

Imagine I have a rails app running on heroku with very minimal traffic in terms of *user* requests, they can be happily served by 1 web dyno.

I also have a machine somewhere in the world which is regularly and repeatedly submitting large files to my application via http://example.com/api/bigupload as fast as it is able.

The large files eat up my web dynos and so the user experience is bad. I increase the web dynos, but the large file uploads continue to tie them all up in long requests.

#### Question

Is there some way I can keep one worker in 'reserve' which will **not** respond to the big upload requests and concentrate on serving user traffic for other URLs?

*Note: I have a similar situation to this one where automated large image uploads are eating my requests and delaying users accessing the API, albeit on a larger scale.*

Comment: I don't know how to achieve what you're asking, but have you looked into using a [background worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)?  This will cost the same as a second dyno (actually less if you start/stop the worker as needed, rather than leaving a second dyno running constantly).

Comment: Yes, I actually use background workers extensively to post-process the images and minimise the impact on the request time. However the initial point of contact (the upload) still eats a dyno for it's duration which is what I'd like to isolate resources for

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something here, but why not just run the upload process in a background worker, too?

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as @digijim - sounds like you have control over the other machine to upload, so why not have that upload the file to S3 (or a similar service) then have your background worker simply "open" that file over the internet for processing?

Comment: I can certainly do that, it's on my list of options, but it would require a shared state between the machine uploading and the heroku app so that the machine knows in what form to upload the file to S3 so the heroku app can correctly load it.

Comment: Although I suppose you could actually just upload it and then POST the location of the file, then convention doesn't matter. That's a more useful twist on my original S3 plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're effectively asking: "Is there a way to partition my web dynos so that only some respond to a certain subset of requests".

The answer (today) is no unfortunately.  Heroku routes randomly across all your web dynos.

What web server are you running on your web dyno?  Are you using a [concurrent web server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/optimizing-dyno-usage#concurrent-web-servers)?  If you're not, that may have a large impact (in that it won't tie the dyno up nearly as much).

Have you explored a different architecture where instead of your other app submitting big uploads, it submits pointers to the big payloads.  That way your web dyno can simply dump them on a queue, and your workers can fetch the payloads and process - and then you can scale by increasing the number of workers.

Comment: I came to the same consclusions and as of now, this is the method I'm implementing. It's a bit more complex and means the jobs just run for slightly longer in the background but I can upload new files faster and therefore handle more traffic whilst scaling workers according to queue backlog which is easier to monitor. If I find a better way I'll update but for now I'm happy(ish)